# Why is my discord bot returning result from mongoDB as undefined when inside of a setInterval and setTimeout function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, command, discord.js

I'm trying to add an hourly command to my discord bot. Every hour it should find all users and add money to them. The command works perfectly fine when it is not inside of a setinterval or settimeout function. However, the command needs to run every hour so the setInterval command is the best option. Here is my code.

```
const economy = require('./economy')
const profileSchema = require('./schemas/profile-schema')
module.exports = async client => {

        let J = 0
        
        var interval = setInterval (function () {
            profileSchema.find({

            }).exec(async (err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
                console.log(res.length)
                if (res.length === 0) {
                    console.log('No users.')
                    return
                } else {
                console.log(res.length)
                    for ( i= 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                        const userId = res[i].userId
                        let hourly = await economy.hourlyIncome(userId)
                        await economy.addCoins(userId, hourly)

                        if (i < res.length) {
                            J = 0
                        }
                    }
                    // console.log('Done')
                }
                console.log('Done')
        
            })
        }, 3000); 
}
```

the exact error says:

```
/Users/*******/discordFamilyBot/hourlyIncome.js:14
                console.log(res.length)
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I've tried putting the function inside of a setInterval loop indirectly but even that ran the same error.

Comment: Did you remove the contents of the object passed when using find()? If you have removed it to upload it to SO, are you sure it's the right query?

Comment: No I did not remove the contents and it is fetching from the correct query. Because if I run the command outside of the setInterval function it works perfectly.

Comment: Is the code as it is here? Because there's nothing in the find object.

Comment: Yeah, when the find object is empty it looks at everything. Atleast it worked like that